# XAMPP loaded modules cause 500 in .htaccess

Tags: module, xampp

Why I get error 500? It's caused by `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    Header set cache-control: public
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html             "access plus 1 days"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml   "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/png             "access plus 10 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg             "access plus 10 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg            "access plus 10 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif             "access plus 10 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg             "access plus 10 month"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg             "access plus 10 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4             "access plus 10 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon          "access plus 10 month"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf              "access plus 10 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml         "access plus 10 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Removing both sections

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
```

resolves problem.

I use XAMPP and those modules are present in `\xampp\apache\modules`:

```
mod_expires.so
mod_headers.so
```

Both are loaded with `\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

Server was restarted.

Comment: I got no error using your supplied configuration here with xampp v1.7.7 on win7. maybe you need to show us the code which caused error

Comment: What code? Removing above sections resolves problem isin't problem there?